# #Flutter Creating a loop to make videocalls based on a given selected person

Tags: flutter, dart, agora.io

I'm new to flutter and developing in general, and the question I have is regarding to using a do/while, while loop in a function to make a video call.
I'm using Agora.sdk to handle that, and Firestore. It's an app similar to Be my eyes, but with a little twist.

First, there are two separate users: the volunteer (which does not do any call) and the visually impaired (who makes the call).

So, I managed to get the volunteers randomly using this code on the onpressed:

onPressed: () async {
                  selectingVolunteers(
                      oneVolunteer);
                  await Permissions.cameraAndMicrophonePermissionsGranted()
                      ? CallUtils.dial(
                          from: sender,
                          to: oneVolunteer,
                          context: context,
                        )
                      : Navigator.pop(context);
                },

It works, but now I need so that if given a certain amount of time, say, 30sec, it calls the selectionVolunteers() again and so on.. ultil any of the volunteers registered answers, or after say.. 5 iterations. I'm not sure how to use the timer thing.. so.. I've created this code:

```
searchAlgorithm(oneVolunteer) async {
     int tries = 0

    do {
      selectingVolunteers(oneVolunteer);
      await Permissions.cameraAndMicrophonePermissionsGranted()
          ? CallUtils.dial(from: sender, to: oneVolunteer, context: context)
          : Navigator.pop(context);
      if (startTimer()) {
        tries++;
        selectingVolunteers(oneVolunteer);
        await Permissions.cameraAndMicrophonePermissionsGranted()
            ? CallUtils.dial(from: sender, to: oneVolunteer, context: context)
            : Navigator.pop(context);
      }
    } while (tries == 5);
  }

  startTimer() {
    const oneSec = const Duration(seconds: 30);
    _timer = new Timer.periodic(
      oneSec,
      (Timer timer) => setState(
        () {
          if (_start < 1) {
            timer.cancel();
          } else {
            _start = _start - 1;
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

But something tells me it's not gonna work :(

I really appreciate all help! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So the reason why your do-while loop might not be working is that you haven't defined the condition properly.

When you declared the `tries` as 0 the compiler takes that value into that loop and runs the code inside it but then when it checks the condition `tries==5` which is not true in this case, hence the loop breaks and your code is getting executed only once (which is default in the case of do-while loops).

So to execute this do while loop 5 times you can do this

```
    do{
        ..... // Your code
        tries++;
      }while(tries<5)
```

This way whenever you're executing this do while loop `tries` will go from 0 to 4 and your code that is inside the do while loop will be executed 5 times.